# sending textbox data to online website textbox (POST Data and GET data) using android studio

Tags: java, android

I want to **send(POST)** my textbox data from android application to any website textbox(which not belong to me) and get back (GET) result after sending data.

Comment: You just can't send your data to any website over the internet. You need APIs to send data to the server and the website can use that data from the server.

Comment: sentence correction.

Comment: you can use selinium java library, hope that helps